# Gnuplot: Points out of lines and palette legend

Tags: gnuplot

I'm trying to plot a secondary structure graphic for a protein during time.
My data look like this:

```
1 0 0
2 0 0
3 0 1
4 0 1
5 0 2
etc..
```

With the third column set as the color.

The code I'm using is this:

```
set terminal pdf
set output 'test.pdf'
set pm3d map
set palette maxcolors 7
set palette model RGB defined (0 "white",1 "red", 2 "purple", 3 "magenta", 4 "brown", 5 "yellow", 6 "blue")
set cbtics ("Coil" 0, "Pi-helix" 1, "3-10 helix" 2, "α-helix" 3, "Bridge" 4, "β-sheet" 5, "β-turn" 6)
set autoscale yfix
set autoscale xfix
splot 'sec_str_tl_cMD.dat' u 2:1:3 w p notitle palette
```

And generates this output:

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQqB3.png)

The problems are:

1 - The points exit the borders.

2 - The palette legends exit the image.

Changing point type or size seems not to work in combination with palette, which I would like to keep.

I searched for solutions, but still haven't find a proper one.
Anyone has any idea on how to fix these problems?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to use splot (3D projection) or pm3d for this plot, since it is a purely 2D plot of colored points.

```
set palette <whatever>
set auto xy
set pointsize <whatever>
plot 'sec_str_tl_cMD.dat' u 2:1:3 with points pointtype 5 lc palette
```

Comment: Thanks, with plot instead of splot I can indeed change the point type. I used pt 0, so now  the points barely exit the axes. Palette legend is, almost completely, inside the image.